# Reset password link returns blank page

Tags: magento-1.8

The reset password email link returns a blank page.
I have updated the custom layout customer.xml after reading the changes needed after the supee 6788 update (resetpassword re-named to changeforgotten) flushed cache and the page still returns blank.
I checked the exception log and have the following;

```
ERR (3): exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Changeforgotten' in /public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27796): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27738): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('customer/accoun...', Array)
#2/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27773): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('customer/accoun...', 'changeForgotten...')
#3/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27540): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('customer/accoun...', 'changeForgotten...')
#4/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27506): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27511): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(13893): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(13818): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(767): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#9/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(13967): Mage_Customer_AccountController->changeForgottenAction()
#10/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18362): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('changeforgotten')
#11/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(17892): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20517): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

Comment: On further investigation I found that the /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php file permissions were not set to execute. The permissions have been updated cache flushed but the reset password page is still blank